# Setting two result sets with a linq to entity statement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Currently I have a linq to entity statement that returns a PagesList of result objects. These get passed to my viewmodel which get used and displayed in my view.
Can I set a second property of my viewmodel without running the linq query twice?

Here is some of my code.

Here is my service layer where I fetch events. You can see I set all events to viewModel.SpaceEvents, but I also want to set viewModel.mapEvents without running the linq query twice

```
        using (var dbContext = new MyContext())
        {
            viewModel.SpaceEvents = (from u in dbContext.SpaceEvents
                orderby u.LocationPoints.Distance(location)
                where
                    (u.EventDateTime >= Date) &&
                    (u.LocationPoints.Distance(location) <= 8047)
                select new SpaceEventResult
                {
                    SpaceId = u.SpaceRefId,
                    // set all remaining the properties here
                }).ToPagedList(Page, 5);

             viewModel.mapEvents = (from u in dbContext.SpaceEvents
                     orderby u.LocationPoints.Distance(location)
                where
                    (u.EventDateTime >= Date) &&
                    (u.LocationPoints.Distance(location) <= 8047)
                select new MapEventResult
                {
                    // set just the map properties here
                }).ToList()
        }
        return viewModel;
```

Then in my view I pass in 'Events' through the viewModel to use, but I don't want to pass all that data to javascript to use for google maps, I only want to pass some of it.

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.Home.EventsViewModel

<script>
    var viewModelMapData = @Model.Events; // I don't want to pass all event data, just map data
</script>
```

Here is part of my viewmodel

```
public IPagedList<EventResult> Events { get; set; }
public IList<MapEventResult> MapEvents { get; set; }
```

Comment: It means I don't want to have to write another linq to entity statement to get another list of objects just for map data. In addition to filling spaceEvents I want to fill a mapObject list as well!

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I've modified my original question

Comment: MapEventResult is NOT a subset of SpaceEventResult. It's a different property in the viewModel. The objective I'm trying to reach is to have both objects filled with similar data, so that one can be passed to the view, and used, and other can be passed to Javascript. I guess I was trying to save space/time/etc by only passing values I needed into Javascript and not SpaceEventResult, which would contain lots of data my map doesn't need!